# Regular Expression error in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regular expression on php to validate dates:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/([12][0-9]{3})$/i",$date_born)){
```

But i got the following error and don't know why, i always used "(" with Reg Exps.

> [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got numerous unescaped `/` inside your pattern:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[01etc...
                                           ^---
```

Easiest is to switch to another delimiter:

```
if(!preg_match("#^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[01etc...
                ^----
```

or escape all the internal `/`:

```
if(!preg_match("/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[01 etc...
                                           ^^---
```

Comment: Thanks, i escaped the internal :P

Comment: @user1511579 Double-quotes for encapsulating regexes = bad (IMHO). You end up doing things like passing literal control characters to PCRE instead of escape sequences, or accidentally passing variables in - which could open up a security hole.

Answer (score 2):

You have your delimiter character `/` within your regex. You need to escape it with `\/` (or change your delimiter as Marc B points out).

```
if( !preg_match("/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([12][0-9]{3})$/i",$date_born)){
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't escape your forward slashes in your regex, so the interpreter reads only to your second forward slash and assumes the rest is all modifiers. Since a `(` modifier doesn't exist, the regex breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Why make this difficult for yourself with regular expressions - use [strptime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) instead.